# Unsure why ODE non-exact equation solution is wrong?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question I'm trying to solve is $$\left(y-4y^6\right)=\left(y^4+5x\right)y'$$ where $y(0)=1$

I want to find the solution explicitly for $x$. I found the integration factor to be $u=y^-6$. Multiplying the equation by the integrating factor, I get $(y^{-5}-4)+(-y^{-2}-5xy^{-6})y'=0$ and then I solved $\int \:(y^{-5}-4)dx=xy^{-5}-4x+g(y)$ and $\int \left(\:-y^2-5xy^{-6}\right)dy=xy^-5-y^{3}/3+h(x)$, combining the two equations, I got $C$=$-1/3$ and $h(x)=-4x$ and $g(y)=-y^3/3$. Then solving the equation, I got $$x=\frac{y^5-y^8}{12y^5-3}$$ But this is not the correct answer. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What's the correct answe?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct answer is. I just know my answer is not correct, but I can't seem to find the mistake

Comment: I think you need to review your integration.  Just take it step by step!

Comment: could you tell me which step? I've checked my integrals several times.

Comment: I cannot follow your solution, but one way out is to consider writing the differential equation pretending $x$ is a function of $y$ and to use for example integrating factor. (Maybe that is what you do, but as mentioned, I cannot follow your steps.)

Comment: Make sure you got the right integrating factor.  Multiply the eq.  by the integrating factor and it should be exact if you have the right integrating factor!

Comment: I just checked the integrating factor, it is exact

Comment: Yes it is exact!

Comment: As I said you have an integration problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is marked on the screen copy below :

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice that you were able to follow OPs calculations...

Comment: @ mickep : I don't like the symbolic writing of Lebron James for partial integration. But to make more clear the correction, I didn't changed it.

Answer (score 1):

The comments do not seem to lead to anything fruitful. I give you the first step, and then you confirm that you have the same in your solution, OK?

Write the differential equation as
$$
x'-\frac{5}{y-4y^6}x=\frac{y^3}{1-4y^5}
$$
Thus, an integrating factor is
$$
\exp\Bigl(\int-\frac{5}{y-4y^6}\,dy\Bigr).
$$
I get it to be

> $$-4+\frac{1}{y^5}.$$

Using this, I get the final solution to be

> $$x=\frac{(1-y)y^4}{4y^5-1}.$$